# Android ListView height does not change when item visibility changed to VISIBLE from GONE

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView. When a row is tapped some buttons's visibility switches between  visible and gone. But I find that **the ListView's height stays the same no matter how many buttons show up. Row height does change though.** Can you tell me how to update/refresh ListView? RelativeLayout is used in both Activity layout that contains ListView and Adapter layout that contains buttons.

```
> listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
>                 View toolbarView = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>                 toolbarView.requestLayout();
>                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) toolbarView.getLayoutParams();
>                 if(toolbarView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
>                     toolbarView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>                     layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0 - toolbarView.getHeight();
> 
>                 }
>                 else{
>                     toolbarView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>                     layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
> 
>                 }
>                 toolbarView.requestLayout();
>             }
>         });
```

ListView:

> ```
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/list_collections"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:divider="@color/list_divider"
>     android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
>     android:background="#13ff3f"
>     android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
> ```

Adapter Layout

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/book_title"
>     android:text="XXXXXX"
>     android:textSize="@dimen/book_title_size"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
>     android:layout_row="0"
>     android:layout_column="0"
>     android:textStyle="bold"
>     android:layout_gravity="left"/>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/book_latest_chapter"
>     android:text="XXXX"
>     android:layout_row="1"
>     android:layout_column="0"
>     android:layout_columnSpan="2"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/book_title"
>     android:layout_gravity="left"/>
>
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/book_actions"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
>     android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_grey"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:clickable="true"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/book_title" />
>
> <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
>     android:visibility="visible"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/book_progress"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/book_action_remove"
>         android:text="XX"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:textColor="@color/color_white"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_background"
>         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/delete"
>         android:layout_margin="5dip"
>         android:gravity="center"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/book_action_toc"
>         android:text="XXX"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:textColor="@color/color_white"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_background"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/book_action_remove"
>         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/toc"
>         android:layout_margin="5dip"
>         android:gravity="center"/>
>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: As a suggestion have you heard of an `ExpandableListView` which creates a very simple interface to handle this for you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Yes but I thought there is no "child item" in my case so I don't need it. I may go back to it if no solution is found for ListView. Thank you!

Comment: The toolbar would be the single child view, the rest would be the group view